# How to call function to change viewController from UITableViewCell class in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need call a function from a UITableViewCell class to change viewController, but I get:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
 class Custom: UITableViewCell{
      var myClass: MyClass!
       myClass = MyClass()
        myClass.call()
}

 class MyClass: UIViewController {
     func call (){
         let nextView =  self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as    MyViewController

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)
     } 
 }
```

How can do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through, but I suspect that the view controller instantiation is failing - probably because "view" isn't the identifier.  It would be better to create a segue from the view controller to your new view controller and then invoke `self.performSegueWithIdentifier()`

Comment: I get error "has no segue with identifier 'segueUnl''" but I have this identifier.. what is the reason?

Comment: Don't confuse the view controller identifier with the segue identifier.

Comment: I select segue, go to Storyboard Segue and write in identifier the name. In segue I have Push and in destination Current

Comment: Also, I noticed now that you are instantiating a new instance of `MyClass`, so even if you do get it to work you will probably get a message to the effect that you are attempting to present from a view controller that is not in the view hierarchy and you will have problems because the navigation controller for your new My lass instance will also be nil. I suggest you use a delegation pattern to enable the cell to request the containing view controller to perform the segue

Comment: BUt.. If I ese something like this:protocol ViewControllerBDelegate {
    func requiredText() -> String
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
            self.theLabel.text = actualDelegate.requiredText()
        }
    }
}        Need I instance delegate in the other class to receive data?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call function like that you must have to definw some method and than call that function! for example

```
class Custom: UITableViewCell{
  var myClass: MyClass=MyClass()
 func callMethod(){

 myClass.call()
}
}
```

Comment: you are calling myClass.call() method directly as you must have to call this under the function of same class!   so i created method callMethod and then calling function from myClass!